# Python скрипт в командной строке выводит не все выходные данные, почему?

Tags: python, cmd

Моя программа выводит на экран все уникальные слова из текстового файла и то сколько раз они встречаются.
Часть кода:

```
for word in Counter(Text).most_common(): #перебирает все слова в отсортированном по убыванию списке
    if len(word[0]) > 1 and word[0] not in My_Vocabulary: #если слово больше, чем из одного символа и не находится в моем словаре
        New_Words.write(word[0]+'\n') #записать его в список новых слов
        Total += 1
        print(word[0], ' - ', word[1]) #вывести на экран это слово и сколько раз оно встречается в тексте
```

В оболочке Python все выводит правильно, но когда запускаю через командную
строку (двойным нажатием) выводит только последние где-то 300 слов.,
а первые только успевают промелькнуть на экране. А когда прокручиваю в командной строке
наверх там их уже нет. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию CMD Windows отображает 300 строк.
Можно поменять в настройках, изменив параметр "Screen Buffer Size – Размер буфера экрана"

Но лучше сохранять данные в файл.

```
file_path = 'путь до файла' # например results.txt
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    for word in Counter(Text).most_common(): #перебирает все слова в отсортированном по убыванию списке
        if len(word[0]) > 1 and word[0] not in My_Vocabulary: #если слово больше, чем из одного символа и не находится в моем словаре
            New_Words.write(word[0]+'\n') #записать его в список новых слов
            Total += 1
            f.write(f'{word[0]} - {word[1]}\n') #записать в файл это слово и сколько раз оно встречается в тексте
```